# XML regular expressions syntax

Tags: regex, syntax, xsd

I've asked this question on [Wikipedia's Reference Desk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Computing/2011_April_24#XML_regular_expressions_syntax), but got no answer. On my second try user Mr.98 redirected me here, so here I am ;)

I'm trying to write my own regexp parser, thus I read related W3C documents. The standard document [XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/) gives [the following definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-normalc) for `normal character` (with a well-known bug of lacking curly braces):

> A normal character is any XML character that is not a metacharacter. (...)
>
> `[10] Char  ::= [^.\?*+()|#x5B#x5D]`

Then the comment appears:

> Note that a ·normal character· can be represented either as itself, or with a character reference. http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-xml-2e-20000814#dt-charref

I'm not very fluent in English and I am not sure how to understand that. If authors put a special emphasis on the possibility of representing ·normal characters· with character references then I expect that such representation for [metacharacters](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-metac) is not allowed. Am I right at this point?

And if I am, what are the implications, if a character reference specifies a code point of a metacharacter, say asterisk, as in `a&#42;`?

1. Is this expression simply invalid?
2. Or rather the reference becomes implicitly a normal character, and the expression is equivalent to `a\*` (with asterisk escaped)?
3. Something else?

All examples I have found with Google use character references to put metacharacters in [chargroups](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-chargroup) of [character class expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-charexpr). However the `Char` symbol appears in the production 9 of regexp syntax, as one of three versions of an [`Atom`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-atom), and neither `Atom` nor `Char` itself is used to define any kind of `chargroup` -- an [`XmlChar`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#nt-XmlChar) is used instead, which in turn has no comment attached about character references usage.

Please clarify the mess in my head:

- Does a metacharacter specified with a character reference become a normal character? How should  `a&#42;` work?
- Is a character reference valid between `[` and `]` (inside [character class expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-charexpr))?

> •we're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users can only post a maximum of two hyperlinks.

Well, I think they would help readers to get into appropriate parts of the half-megabyte W3C document. But do as you wish - I've converted them into ugly-looking, hard-to-read ordinary text. Of course I might strip them entirely from the post -- but I do **not** belive the robot is right in this case.

Comment: Are you writing your own regexp parser, or XML Schema parser now? Or both? If it is just a general regexp parser, I think you look at the wrong specification; you should rather look at some Perl documents, as the standard regular expression syntax is usually borrowed directly from Perl. Note that you can completely define your own syntax though..

Comment: @poke: I'm working in a company that develops SCADA systems. We make an extensive use of XML in new generation of our products. I am involved in a project of a converter program to move our customers' data from old systems to a new one. Some part of data processing is done wih XQuery scripts, and I need to implement fn:matches and fn:replace properly. Useful external libraries are either commercial and closed (we couldn't port them freely to different compilers or executing hardware platforms) or inherently free (GPL-based licensing) so we do everything ourselves. :)

Comment: @poke: (contd.) Through the years I worked with Borland Turbo Pascal 3 through 5.5 and occasionally with Delphi 4 through 7, several versions of C/C++ compilers and IDE tools from Zortech, Watcom, Borland and Microsoft, also with MS Word, MultiEdit, BeyondCompare, vi, grep and awk - so I am aware of regular expressions syntax and semantics diversity (like parens being backref. delimiters or just a grouping symbol with braces for backreferences).

Comment: @poke: (contd.) I'm trying to design the core machine rather general, so I could quite easily redefine it by substituting another lexical scanner and/or symbol/handler table (or just virtual functions to handle specific grammar issues). However right now I need those XQuery functions, and in this context I suppose I ought to follow http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax which in turn refers to http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/ and hence my question. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**does a metacharacter specified with a character reference become a normal character? How should a* work?**

No, it becomes `a*` and * is still a meta character which can be escaped as `\*`

Coming to the next question:

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256185.aspx

```
charRange ::= seRange | XmlCharRef | XmlCharIncDash
```

where

```
XmlCharRef ::= ( '&#' [0-9]+ ';' ) | ('&#x' [0-9a-fA-F]+ ';' )
```

But from w3,

```
charRange ::= seRange | XmlCharIncDash
```

the XmlCharRef is not included. So,

**is a character reference valid between [ and ] (inside character class expressions(http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-charexpr))?**

No